# Extract text from PDF got generated from autocad using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I have got a PDF generated from AutoCad, I have used all python libraries to extract the text out of it (PyPDF2, PDFMiner,...) and all of them return empty text.

I have noticed that those PDFs are not a free text, e.g. I can NOT select any text in it, its like a picture or something

How can I extract the text out of it ? is this even possible or is there any library to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Extract images from the pdf using PyMuPDF, & then use pytesseract to extract text out of the images.

[Documentation to PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-images.html)

Comment: Thats brilliant! I'm unable to get any image, however, I tried get_pixmap and seems that I have some details, do you know any library to convert pixmap to text?

Comment: PyMuPDF has an inbuilt interface to dynamically invoke Tesseract-OCR by passinh images (incl. Pixmaps) to it.